# pandas: replace NaN with the last non-NaN value in column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, missing-data

I have an excel file which lists basketball teams and the players on each team. The first row for a new team states the team name in column 0 and a player on that team in column 1. The next row simply has a player on that team in column 1 (nothing in column 0 as the team is implied from the last stated team). This is repeated for every team.

```
Warriors    Stephen Curry
-           Klay Thompson
-           Kevin Durant
Clippers    Chris Paul
-           Blake Griffen
-           JJ Redick
Raptors     Kyle Lowry
-           Demar Derozan
```

I'm importing the data into a pandas dataframe and counting the number of players on each team.

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_excel('data.xlsx')
print(df)

     Team        Player
0    Warriors    Stephen Curry
1    NaN         Klay Thompson
2    NaN         Kevin Durant
3    Clippers    Chris Paul
4    NaN         Blake Griffen
5    NaN         JJ Redick
6    Raptors     Kyle Lowry
7    NaN         Demar Derozan
```

Is there anyway I can replace `NaN` with the appropriate team name (I know I just need to fill in the empty spots in the excel file but it looks much cleaner if I handle this on the import or via pandas). I imagine I need to iterate through the dataframe, store the team name if it's not `NaN` and replace `NaN` with the currently stored team name until a new team arises.

If you don't know basketball, my dataframe should look like this when all is said and done:

```
     Team        Player
0    Warriors    Stephen Curry
1    Warriors    Klay Thompson
2    Warriors    Kevin Durant
3    Clippers    Chris Paul
4    Clippers    Blake Griffen
5    Clippers    JJ Redick
6    Raptors     Kyle Lowry
7    Raptors     Demar Derozan
```

Comment: Note that -- as some of the answers in the linked dup mention -- you can use `.ffill()` directly these days.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this using the [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method on the dataframe. The `method='ffill'` tells it to fill forward with the last valid value.

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```